# Return random attribute in entity (Core Data)

Tags: ios, swift, database, core-data

[verbDatabase Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIHsi.png)
The data I'm using is the below and also in the screenshot above:

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| id | infinitive | ind pre je | ind pre tu |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | aimer      | aime       | aimes      |
|  2 | aller      | vais       | vas        |
|  3 | courir     | cours      | cours      |
|  4 | servir     | sers       | sers       |
|  5 | mourir     | meurs      | meurs      |
|  6 | dormir     | dors       | dors       |
|  7 | sentir     | sens       | sens       |
|  8 | vêtir      | vêts       | vêts       |
|  9 | fuir       | fuis       | fuis       |
| 10 | tenir      | tiens      | tiens      |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
```

I'm new to coding and am working on a French conjugation app that tests users on their conjugation by displaying a verb in infinitive form (to verbLabel.text) and the tense required (to tenseLabel.text). The goal is for the user to input (to userInput.text)the conjugated form of that verb and press a button (checkAnswer) to check their answer. If the answer is correct, a new verb will be generated, etc.

I have a CoreData entity named `verbDatabase` with attributes named `id`, `infinitive`, `indPreJe` and `indPreTu`.

I've managed to generate a random row (to display a random verb) but I'm having trouble generating a random attribute (either indPreJe or indPreTu). To generate a random attribute and because attribute names must begin with a lowercase letter, I cannot use the same method as I did to generate a random row.

To solve this problem, I tried creating an array which holds attribute names and then generate a random number that then appends the attribute name to the fetch request that is displayed in tenseLabel.text but tenseLabel.text displays the string `"verbDatabase[0].indPreJe"` instead of the value of `verbDatabase[0].indPreJe`.

Is there any way to get the text label to display the value after it has been appended with the random attribute name instead of the string points to that value?

If I'm tackling my data in an inefficient way, is there a better way of storing my data into Core Data that will allow me to better access it with what I'm trying to do? I'm still trying to wrap my head around the Core Data structure. I've also considered saving the verbs as separate dictionaries with the tenses as their keys and conjugated forms as their corresponding values.

Ideally I would like to be able to allow users to select which tenses they would like to be tested on and also categorising the verbs - regular form, irregular form, common verbs, etc.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
@IBOutlet weak var verbLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tenseLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var userInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
var currentRow: Int = 0
var countTenseColumns: Int = 2
var currentColumn: Int = 0
var columnNames = ["id","infinitive","indPreJe","indPreTu"]

@IBAction func checkAnswer(_ sender: Any) {

    if userInput.text == verbDatabase[currentRow].indPreTu {
        textView.text = "correct!"
        viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        userInput.text = nil
    }

    else {
     textView.text = "the correct answer is \(verbDatabase[currentRow].indPreTu ?? "error")"

    }
}

func randomNumberGeneratorRow() -> Int {
    //generates random number from 1 to verbDatabase.count
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(verbDatabase.count)+1))
}

func randomNumberGeneratorColumn() -> Int {
    //generates random number from 2 to number of columns with tenses
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(countTenseColumns)+2))
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    currentRow = self.randomNumberGeneratorRow()
    currentColumn = self.randomNumberGeneratorColumn()
    var columnName = "verbDatabase[0].\(columnNames[currentColumn])"

    verbLabel.text = verbDatabase[currentRow].infinitive
    tenseLabel.text = columnName     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to get the text label to display the value after it has been appended with the random attribute name instead of the string points to that value?

Yes, you can use `value(forKey:)` (see [the documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1412591-value)):

```
var columnName = columnNames[currentColumn]
tenseLabel.text = verbDatabase[currentRow].value(forKey:columnName)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was beginning to worry I had to reformat my data! 
Just for completeness, Swift made me add 
`as! String`:                                                                                                    
`tenseLabel.text = verbDatabase[currentRow].value(forKey:columnName) as! String`